# svn dump file : How Are Key/Value Numbers Determined

Tags: svn

In an svn dump file:

For either a revision record or a node record, you have a set of keys and values describing the properties section.

For example :

```
K 8
svn:date
V 27
2013-05-25T15:38:48.105514Z
K 7
```

How are the integers for the keys generated and how are the integers for the values generated?

```
For instance, we have a key as 8 and a value with 27 above.
```

Comment: Just a guess: The keys are generated sequentially, and the value is the length (there are 27 characters in the value you posted).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number contains the length of the key/value in octets. See the format specification for more details: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/notes/dump-load-format.txt